# Layers in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want create view like this, using layers. (like in swift `maskLayer`). Can I do somthing in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: You can use `Stack` widget.

Comment: I will change circle radius dynamicly

Comment: It will work, `Stack` simply puts the `children` on top of the previous. check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) reference.

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: There are similar questions on stackoverflow, [this is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50348804/13625305) of them.

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Circle not in transparent mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This is a crude version and might not be the best/efficient way of achieving the result.

I have created a very rough version for the UI [code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0VZVsaka).

Used [this answer by @Yann39](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373963/13625305) as a starting point.

Used `CustomPainter` for the hole and `Stack` for layout.
You will have to refine the code according to your needs.

This is the output:
[image: crude version]